# Using Scala reflection to check for a method on an object or to find key type on a Map

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-reflect

I am porting a class from Ruby to Scala 2.11 that implements variable merging in messages. I would like to pass an array of objects to the merge method and have it search each object for the keys that are referenced in the text of the message.

The core of this is a method called lookUp(key: String, obj: AnyRef) which receives a single key for which to search, and a single object on which to search for the key. If the object is a Map, and the Map's keys are either Symbol or String, then it will look in the Map for the requested key. Otherwise it will check if the object has a method with the same name of the key, and if so, it will invoke that method.

In the existing Ruby code, it is trivially easy to do this:

```
def look_up(key, obj)
  if obj.respond_to?(:has_key?) && obj.has_key?(key)
    obj[key]
  elsif obj.respond_to?(key)
    obj.send(key)
  elsif obj.instance_variable_defined?(ivar = "@#{key}")
    obj.instance_variable_get(ivar)
  end
end
```

Since it's easy to do so, the Ruby code also looks for an instance variable of the same name. I don't necessarily need that functionality in my Scala version.

One of the issues I am having is that the examples I've found require that I know the object's class ahead of time so I can call `ru.typeOf[MyClass].declaration(ru.TermName("key"))` (where `ru` is `scala.reflect.runtime.universe`).

Another issue is that this message merge can be happening hundreds of times per minute, and reflection seems to be a slow, involved process. If this all works as planned, I'll likely cache the reflection results by object type.

UPDATE: I was thinking about something like this, but is this overkill? Or is it necessary to properly capture the types in the Map? Also, this doesn't compile. `Map`, `Symbol` and `String` aren't the right types for their context.

```
def lookUp[T](obj: T, key: String)(implicit tag: ru.TypeTag[T]): Option[String] = tag.tpe match {
  case ru.TypeRef(a, Map, List(Symbol, _)) => if (obj.contains(Symbol(key))) Some(obj(Symbol(key)).toString) else None
  case ru.TypeRef(a, Map, List(String, _)) => if (obj.contains(key)) Some(obj(key).toString) else None
  case _ =>
    if (/* obj.key() exists */)
      // Some(obj.key().toString)
    else
      None
}
```

UPDATE 2: It never occurred to me that I could use `asInstanceOf` with something like `Map[String, _]`. I used @johny's second example of code to come up with my solution. I cache the method names by class in a `mutable.HashMap[Class[_], Set[String]]`.

```
def lookUp(obj: AnyRef, key: String): Option[String] = obj match {
  case m: Map[_, _] =>
    if (m.asInstanceOf[Map[String, _]].contains(key))
      extractValue(m.asInstanceOf[Map[String, _]](key))
    else if (m.asInstanceOf[Map[Symbol, _]].contains(Symbol(key)))
      extractValue(m.asInstanceOf[Map[Symbol, _]](Symbol(key)))
    else
      None
  case _ =>
    val klass = obj.getClass
    if (!methodsCache.contains(klass))
      methodsCache(klass) = klass.getMethods.toList.filter(_.getParameterCount == 0).map(_.getName).toSet
    val methodNames = methodsCache(klass)
    if (methodsCache(klass).contains(key))
      extractValue(klass.getDeclaredMethod(key).invoke(obj))
    else
      None
}

def extractValue(obj: Any): Option[String] = obj match {
  case null | None => None
  case Some(x) => Some(x.toString)
  case x => Some(x.toString)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 def lookUp(key: String, obj: AnyRef) {
    obj match {
      case x: Map[String, _] => x(key)
      case _                 => obj.getClass.getDeclaredMethod(key).invoke(obj)
    }
  }
```

**Edit: To make sure key of Map is either String or scala.Symbol**

```
def lookUp(key: String, obj: AnyRef)= {
    obj match {
      case x: Map[_, _]  => 
        if(x.asInstanceOf[Map[String,_]].contains(key))
          x.asInstanceOf[Map[String,_]].get(key)
        else if(x.asInstanceOf[Map[scala.Symbol,_]].contains(scala.Symbol(key)))
          x.asInstanceOf[Map[scala.Symbol,_]].get(scala.Symbol(key))
        else
          None

      case _ => Some(obj.getClass.getDeclaredMethod(key).invoke(obj))
    }
  }
```

The above too doesnt make sure the returned output is from the intended `Map`.

**Edit: Following @JimCain's lead**

```
def lookUp[T:ru.TypeTag](obj: T, key: String): Option[Any] = ru.typeTag[T].tpe match {
    case ru.TypeRef(a, m, l) if(m.name.toString=="Map"&&l.head =:= ru.typeOf[java.lang.String])=> obj.asInstanceOf[Map[String,_]].get(key)
    case ru.TypeRef(a, m,l) if(m.name.toString=="Map"&&l.head =:= ru.typeOf[Symbol])=> obj.asInstanceOf[Map[Symbol,_]].get(scala.Symbol(key))
    case _ => Try(obj.getClass.getDeclaredMethod(key).invoke(obj)) match {
      case Success(x) => Some(x)
      case Failure(_) => None
    }
  }
```

Comment: From the REPL: `warning: non-variable type argument String in type pattern scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,_] (the underlying of Map[String,_]) is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure`

Comment: Due to type erasure, type parameters of `Map` is not available. Parameter `String` is added for convenience so that conversion can be avoided. You could also use `@unchecked` annotation like, `Map[String @unchecked, _]`, which will remove the warning. The down side is it will match all `Map`s irrespective of its type parameters.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. However, I want to be able to know whether the keys are `String` or `Symbol` so I know how to reliably look them up. If the keys are neither type, then I want to skip it altogether.

Comment: If Strings and Symbols are the only cases, see edit.

Comment: @JimCain, see this edit. A modification of your code.